# How to load a Picker in Xamarin forms with data received from the Web Api?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So, this is my Model Class "Usuario"

This class has the Foreign key "IdTipoUsuario" that was declared in my database from SQL Server Management Studio. So I placed it here with the "IList" property:

```
namespace APPiGarbage.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public IList<TipoUsuario> TiposUsuarios { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

I have this other class TipoUsuario. This class has the "Nome" property that is supposed to be Binding in the picker.

```
namespace APPiGarbage.Models
{
    public class TipoUsuario
    {
        public int IdTipoUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For my MVVM Model I tried whole lot codes and now I don't even know what to put in it. To be honest.

```
namespace APPiGarbage.ViewModel
{
    public class UsuarioViewModel 
    {
        public List<TipoUsuario> tipos { get; set; }

        public List<Usuario> GetTipos()
        {
            var tipos = new List<Usuario>()
            {

            };
            return tipos;
        }
    }
```

For my ApiService class I have this code:

```
namespace APPiGarbage.API
{
    public class ApiService
    {
        public const string Url = "http://10.0.2.2:44342/";
        public static async Task<List<TipoUsuario>> ObterTipoUsuarios()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string url = Url + "/api/TipoUsuario";
                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                List<TipoUsuario> tipos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TipoUsuario>>(response);
                return tipos;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Picker in my UsuarioPage.xaml:

```
<Picker Title="Selecione o Tipo de Usuario"
             ItemsSource="{Binding TipoUsuario}"
             ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Nome}"/>
```

And finally this is the UsuarioPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace APPiGarbage.Pages.UsuarioPage
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class UsuarioPage : ContentPage
    {
        public UsuarioPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new UsuarioViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: first problem - your Picker's ItemsSource is bound to TipoUsuario, but TipoUsuario is not a property of your VM.  Presumably your ItemsSource should be bound to the `tipos` property.

Comment: A small advice, even though your native language is not English I suggest you stop using Portuguese when coding. That will help you learn better English and it will help you getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your xaml, your Picker's ItemsSource should bind to the tipos in your ViewModel.

```
<Picker Title="Selecione o Tipo de Usuario"
     ItemsSource="{Binding tipos}"
     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Nome}"/>
```

Second, you should get data from Api in ViewModel:

```
public class UsuarioViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TipoUsuario> tipos { get; set; }

    public UsuarioViewModel() {

        Task<List<TipoUsuario>> task = ApiService.ObterTipoUsuarios();

        tipos = new ObservableCollection<TipoUsuario>(task.Result);

    }
}
```

Then the binding should work and feel free to ask me any question if you have.

Comment: Hey @jackhua-msft and thank you for the reply. I put the code and when I started the application I got this message: "Failed to initialize dynamic xaml reload", and the application continues without rendering.  So I commented the BindingContext ´public UsuarioPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //BindingContext = new UsuarioViewModel();
        }´ and the application rendered, but obviously without the picker data. Help me please