# How to get data from Web API to Xamarin forms Picker?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, picker

I'm developing a Xamarin APP and I want to load a Picker with data from a Web API that has Server Database. I tried to Google this but most of the articles don't show the content of source "Services class" that use Get async Method, Model class and ViewModel. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with an example.

This is my Controller in ASP.NET Web API

```
// GET: api/TipoUsers
public IQueryable<TipoUser> GetTipoUsers()
{
    return db.TipoUsers;
}
```

Model class

```
public class TipoUsuario
{
    public int IdTipoUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
public class UsuarioViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TipoUsuario> tipos { get; set; }

    public UsuarioViewModel() {    
        Task<List<TipoUsuario>> task = ApiService.ObterTipoUsuarios();

        tipos = new ObservableCollection<TipoUsuario>(task.Result);    
    }
}
```

Xaml Page

```
<Picker Title="Selecione o Tipo de Usuario"
     ItemsSource="{Binding tipos}"
     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Nome}"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class UsuarioPage : ContentPage
    {
        public UsuarioPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new UsuarioViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Service class

```
public class ApiService
{
    public const string Url = "http://thisismysite:44342/";
    public static async Task<List<TipoUsuario>> GetTipoUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = Url + "/api/TipoUsers";
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            List<TipoUsuario> tipos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TipoUsuario>>(response);
            return tipos;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

when I debug the app it just doesn't load the screen.

Comment: This is extensively documented.  Xamarin provides three **complete** samples with walkthroughs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/.

Comment: @DaleK please help me with examples, I'm newbie ..

Comment: @KKCriativo this isn't the right forum for asking that sort of tutorial/example question. There are loads of other sites out there, SO is for asking when you get stuck on a specific, technical, implementation detail.

Comment: You haven't told us anything useful about your API - what it's signature is, does it require auth, is it RESTful or SOAP or something else?  And I just gave you a link to several examples.

Comment: AND... you posted a similar question two days ago, but that one at least had some useful details on it.

Comment: @Jason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63284584/how-to-load-a-picker-in-xamarin-forms-with-data-received-from-the-web-api?

Comment: that question has an accepted answer - why did you accept the answer if it didn't fix your problem?  The code you use for calling the service appears correct.

Comment: I asked a similar question and after the answers received, I implemented the Code but did not worked. So I wanted someone to show me how this is done using their own examples.

Comment: Sorry I don't even know how this site works

Comment: So show us your code and ask **specific** questions about the problem you're having

Comment: reading [ask] will give you an overview of the site guidelines

Comment: @Jason I already edited and put the code of the classes. Help me please

Comment: 1. Are you sure your service works?  Can you load it in the browser to get json?  2. are you getting any exceptions?  3. is `tipos` being  correctly populated with data?

Comment: Web Api is working and I can load the "Tipos" in json format. but still can't load the app. Xamarin app isn't loading any picker or data it keep in the blank screen

Comment: then you need to **debug the app** to figure out where it is breaking and why.  You didn't answer questions 2&3 I asked you.  If you don't know how to use the debugger, try adding `Console.Writeline(tipos.Count);` after you deserialize to verify that you are getting the data

Comment: Where is ObterTipoUsuarios method in Apiservice?

Comment: @JackHuaMSFT I Changed "ObterTipoUsuarios" to "GetTipoUsers"

Comment: Are you sure if it is correct that the type of response is string?  Check the value of tipos in the GetTipoUsers to see if you get the right data.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a few reasons, I would check your async method isn’t throwing an exception that you aren’t able to see. Async methods return a Task object and if an exception is thrown inside it will be visible in the returned object in Task.Exception.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library

Also property changed events aren’t called when you set an ObserableCollection to a new instance, you want to add and remove from the collection.

You want to change:

```
public UsuarioViewModel() {    
    Task<List<TipoUsuario>> task = ApiService.ObterTipoUsuarios();

    tipos = new ObservableCollection<TipoUsuario>(task.Result);    
}
```

to something like:

```
public UsuarioViewModel() {    
    Task<List<TipoUsuario>> task = ApiService.ObterTipoUsuarios();

    var temptipos = task.Result;
    foreach(var tipo in temptipos)
    {
        tipos.Add(tipo);
    }
}
```